# How to fix "Notification access is not available" on Android Go?

Tags: notifications, permissions, android-go

I have a TECNO Spark 2 running on Android 8.1 Oreo (**Go Edition**). Every time I try to install apps that require notification access, it says that the feature is not available.

[image: A message saying "This feature is not available on this device" when opening Notification access on Android Go]

How to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

**Currently, the only known solution is to revert to the full-fledged Android (may need root access)**.

There have been many reports regarding the issue:

- [I can't enable notifications icons badge on Moto E5 Play](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/204494/44325) (November 2018)
- [Android go notification access issues](https://support.google.com/android/thread/815918) (December 2018)
- [How do I enable notification access on Android Oreo Go edition?](https://support.google.com/wearos/thread/3175783) (March 2019)
- [AutoNotification Paid version, bought Android Go Edition that doesn't have Notification Access feature & have rooted phone, any ideas/workarounds to let AutoNotification to access notifications](https://tasker.helprace.com/i589) (June 2019)
- [Is it possible to enable notifications access on Android Oreo 8.1?](https://support.google.com/android/thread/17566518) (October 2019)
- [Android go notification access problem](https://support.google.com/android/thread/22976008) (December 2019)
- [Notification access not available on this device](https://github.com/Galaxy-MSM8916/android_device_samsung_msm8916-common/issues/42) (December 2019)
- [Notification access - This feature is not available on this device](https://zentalk.asus.com/en/discussion/21013/notification-access-this-feature-is-not-available-on-this-device) (January 2020)
- [Notification access for apps not found how to fix it ...](https://community.phones.nokia.com/discussion/56064/notification-access-for-apps-not-found-how-to-fix-it)
- [Grant notification access via ADB](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60577857/2821954) & [GRANT LAWNCHAIR NOTIFICATION ACCESS VIA ADB](https://www.reddit.com/r/LawnchairLauncher/comments/feuo08/grant_lawnchair_notification_access_via_adb/) (March 2020)

Due to the restriction that is put on Android Go, the notification access is disabled (for more information: [Why is the Android Go's performance better?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/228839/44325))

The only known solution is to revert to the full-fledged Android: [Disable Android Go?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/245964/44325)

Comment: There's a mention of [successfully using App Ops to enable Display Over Other Apps which is also disabled feature on Android Go](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/246036/44325), though [someone said that it didn't work for Notification Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60577857/grant-notification-access-via-adb#comment107179423_60577857). Your mileage may vary.