# I can't enable notifications icons badge on Moto E5 Play

Tags: notifications, 8.1-oreo, android-go

I have a Moto E5 Play with Oreo 8.1(Android Go) and I can't enable notification icons badge, I mean those little dots over the application icons on home.

When I go to Configuration-> Apps Notifications
there's no option to enable it.

If I go to application configuration is there an option to enable it individually but is grayed out.

I search on the web but nothing solve this.

Comment: @beeshyams Yes, I think it is because is an entry level phone and have a lot of Google Go Apps. I think I will make a Nandroid and I will install a true Android Oreo version.

Comment: @beeshyams I just read and seems like is no completely ready the TWRP. It says "... it does not allow decrypting and therefore mounting the data partition and internal storage." https://forum.xda-developers.com/moto-e5/development/moto-e5-plus-rhannah-backup-magisk-root-t3822702/amp/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As discussed in comments, OP's device runs Android Go and has Android Go apps.

Android Go doesn't support notification icons as explained in Lenovo forums [Notification Dot missing on UK phone](https://forums.lenovo.com/t5/Moto-E5-Moto-E5-Plus-Moto-E5/Notification-Dot-missing-on-UK-phone/td-p/4253661)

> ....Android Go does not support notification access to apps,....