# Is it possible to install Android Go Edition in Xiaomi Redmi 2 pro?

Tags: xiaomi, redmi, redmi-2

I have an old Xiaomi Redmi 2 pro from 2015.

[image]

This phone has Android 5.1.1 installed, 16MB capacity and even with a fresh install there's only about 2GB left. I read Android Go is lighter and leaves more space available.

How to install this in this phone? any suggestions?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Based on [my understanding](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/228854/44325), you need to modify the `build.prop` to add `ro.config.low_ram=true` (need to be rooted). However, AFAIK Android GO is more about RAM, not storage. I think you may consider flashing a more lightweight custom ROM instead...

Comment: Redmi 2 pro/Redmi 2 have same chipset, try ROMs for 16GB variant https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=3307136

Comment: I'm new to this, and this flashing and stuff seems confusing :( all those files and ROMS.

Is there an easier way, just to connect the phone to the computer and flash Android Go or another ROM that's light and takes less space than 5.1.1?

Comment: android go not available. select custom ROM, check it's status is stable, follow install instructions. be aware builds are specific for device model. you will always lose all data