# Would there be any restrictions on what apps will work on Android Go?

Tags: applications, compatibility, android-go

I'm looking for a cheap tablet and found this [ACER ACTAB723](https://www.currys.ie/products/acer-actab723-7-tablet-16-gb-black-10240560.html).

It's **Android 12 Go** - my question is, would there be any restrictions on what apps will work on it, compared to a regular Android 12? And, are apps likely to function for as long on the Go edition before they can no longer be updated?

Thanks!

Comment: [I used an Android Go phone for a month, and it was terrible](https://www.androidpolice.com/2018/07/15/used-android-go-phone-month-terrible/) //It all depends on your usage and one never knows how long it will supported by Google and therefore by developers (RIP :Android - one)

Comment: @beeshyams thanks for that. I really only use the tablet to cast Netflix, YT and the like, and the occasional WhatsApp and LINE calls. It seems I cannot assume that if an app works on 12 it will also work on 12 Go?

Comment: I am not sure about the app compatibility or otherwise. I would suggest you buy a regular phone on sales or search the XDA forums for the apps of your interest

Comment: Note that for watching streaming services you usually need a Widevine certification for the device (best Widevice L1). And even if it has the DRM certification it sometimes still not works and you only get SD quality videos (own experience with my 2019 Lenovo Tab P10 with has L1 but Amazon Prime is lmited to SD). Also I have experienced that some modern streaming apps are implemented using react-native programming language which significantly requires more CPU and RAM resources for lag-free watching).

Comment: Hi, I updated the title to reflect the real question about app compatibility because "downsides" is considerably subjective and broad, i.e. [my answer to "Why is the Android Go's performance better?"](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/228839/44325).