# Force Accept Remote Connection

Tags: remote-access, android-go, teamviewer

As the title implies...

Every time I attempt to start an AnyDesk or Teamviewer session I'm met with this giant billboard asking me to allow the connection.

The warning is from Android, not from the apps.

And I need to bypass this

Cannot root this phone, unfortunately...

How ?

: |

Thank you ahead

**P.S.:**

More people would benefit from an universal solution

But **in my case**, the phone is **Android Go**. It has no app overlay option.

For that reason, *Teamviewer Host* does not work.

Comment: That is the way those apps work. If you want to remote control a local device connected via USB you could use [scrcpy](https://github.com/Genymobile/scrcpy).

Comment: Unfortunately, it Must be a remote control...

Comment: So you use [TeamViewer Host](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.teamviewer.host.market)?

Comment: I'm gonna detail on the body of the thread about the TV Host

Comment: Just want to note that [Android Go deliberately disables some of the system services](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/228854/44325). From my finding, the solution is [to not use Android Go](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/228856/44325).