# Disable Android Go?

Tags: android-go

I have a Cricket Icon 2 and it has an Android 10 Go edition. It disabled some of my favorite features like adding widgets or displaying apps over others.

I want to know if there's a way I can disable Android Go?

Comment: Android Go is a separate OS for low-end devices that are not powerful enough to run full Google Android OS. Therefore there is no switch to enable the full functionality.

Answer (score 1):

You need root and root explorer.

Go to `/vendor` and edit the `build.prop` file.  Find the line `ro.config.low_ram=true` and change `true` to `false`.  Then just reboot your device.  All is ready!

Answer (score 1):

Android Go is a device configuration for low-memory usage. Thus to "disable" Android Go, either turn off the configuration for it or use non-Android Go ROMs instead:

- Set `ro.config.low_ram` to `false` on the `build.prop` (**need root access**, as has been mentioned on [MadCreeepyman's answer](https://android.stackexchange.com/a/247167/44325)).
- Downgrade to the previous full-fledged Android version
- Flash a custom ROM that is not based on Android Go