# Enable Display Over Other Apps Android 10-11 Go Edition (Nokia 1.4) when "feature is disabled because it slows down the phone"?

Tags: settings, android-10, overlay, android-go

I have a Nokia 1.4 (TA-1322) running on **Android 11 Go Edition**. I have some apps which need to display over other apps, but whenever I try to enable it in settings, I see this message:

> Feature not available
> This feature has been turned off because it slows down your phone.

---

#### SCREENSHOTS

| Image 1 | Image 2 |
| --- | --- |
| [image: image_1] | [image: image_2] |

Please help me because I really need this feature, or maybe a workaround.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some potential solutions.

***[Edit]: Non PC Solution added below!***

## PC METHOD

### Requirements

- PC/Mac with ADB installed on it. Check [here for ADB installation instructions](https://www.xda-developers.com/install-adb-windows-macos-linux/).
- Package name for app (i.e *com.android.testapp*)
- USB or for connecting to PC or Mac.
- Obviously the phone.

## Step 1: Enable USB Debugging on Android Phone

1. Open **Settings** on your android phone..
2. Navigate to **About Phone**
3. Click **Build Number** several times until developer settings are unlocked. Usually a toast is displayed showing "*You are now a developer*".
4. Now navigate to **Developer Options**. (Which are now unlocked in your settings)
5. Scroll to **USB Debugging** option and enable it.

## Step 2: Connect Android Phone to ADB

1. Open PC/Mac with **ADB installed**. Check [here for ADB installation instructions](https://www.xda-developers.com/install-adb-windows-macos-linux/).
2. Connect Android Phone to PC/Mac via USB cable.
3. Click the notification popup on Android Phone and select **File Transfer**.
4. Open Commmand Prompt/Terminal in the **ADB folder** on PC/Mac (Skip if ADB is installed system wide)
5. Run command `adb devices` for a list of connected devices. The connected device should be available under list of devices! i.e

```
 $ adb devices
List of attached devices
xxxxxxxx            device
 $
```

## Step 3: Determine Android App Package Name

There are many ways to determine the package name of the android app whose permissions are to be enabled, including some below;

1. Making a google search :).
2. Using third party apps i.e [Package Name Viewer](https://www.google.com/search?q=Package%20Name%20Viewer%20apk).
3. Checking the folder on Android phone `Android/data` etc.

Package name may appear like `com.android.testapp`

## Step 4: Enable Permissions

Finally, to enable *Display Over Other Apps* permission for the application, **type below command carefully** into the Command Prompt/Terminal;

**Note:** Replace `<package name>` with package name of your application!

```
adb shell pm grant <package name> android.permission.SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW
```

**OR**

```
adb -d shell appops set <package name> SYSTEM_ALERT_WINDOW allow
```

Now return to your phone settings and check the permissions for the app, they should be granted.

## NON PC METHOD

### Requirements

- Shizuku app (Download from [here](https://shizuku.rikka.app/download/)).
- App Ops (Download from [here](https://appops.rikka.app/)).
- Obviously the phone :).

## Step 1: Install App Requirements

1. **Download** and **install** **Shizuku** app and **App Ops** from Playstore or from below links;

- [Shizuku](https://shizuku.rikka.app/download/)
- [App Ops](https://appops.rikka.app/)

## Step 2: Start Shizuku App

1. Open **Start Shizuku** by following the instructions [here](https://shizuku.rikka.app/guide/setup/?night=1).

I recommend **Start** using **[wireless debugging](https://shizuku.rikka.app/guide/setup/?night=1#start-via-wireless-debugging)** method for those who **don't** want to use **PC** or **root**.

## Step 3: Open App Ops and Grant Permission

1. Now **open App Ops**.
2. You will receive a **prompt** to **chose a working mode**, click on **Shizuku** then **Continue** and **allow shizuku access** from **popup dialog**.
3. If **Shizuku is running**, and **permission granted** to **App Ops** successfully--
4. A list of installed apps will be shown.
5. Click on the app whose permissions are to be modified and--
6. Under **Other**, you will see **Display Over Other Apps** permission.
7. Click and **Grant/Allow**.

Enjoy diplaying windows in Other Apps.

Note: I **have tested** these solutions **on Nokia 1.4** and they **worked successfully**, ***no guarantee for other phones!***

---

Comment: Appreciate the self-answer, does this mean that permission restrictions such as this can be bypassed even on Android Go? If that's the case, then that's really good to know since it might be applicable to other cases!

Comment: @AndrewT. Yes actually...this approach was tested on Nokia 1.4 running Android 11 Go edition...and maybe applicable to other cases.